# Cakephp Admin Prefixed Routing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0

In my Cakephp application i wish to have the following url:

admin/users/:action

I want the UsersController to reside in an sub-folder of Controllers named 'admin'. I know how to implement this with Cake 3 and 4 but in this case I am working with a legacy Cake2 project. I have read the chapter on the router in the Cake2 book, but it seems to deal with this by prefixing controller actions with "admin" using a single main controller.

That's not what I need, I am looking for the following:

```
Controllers
     - [Admin]
          - UsersController
     - UsersContrller
```

That is - two controller and the sub-folder.

I can match the route as follows, but I can't figure out the parameters to use:

```
Router::connect(
    '/integrations/foo/:controller/:action/*',
    []
);
```

Where 'integrations' is my plugin and 'foo' is the sub-folder. I am having doubts if this is actually possible in Cake2. I found an old question from 2013 that says that sub-directories for controllers is no longer supported, but I am not sure if that is a valid statement.

[CakePHP controllers and models in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411780/cakephp-controllers-and-models-in-subdirectory)

Might this need to be done with a redirect at the server level?

Answer (score 1):

In your routes.php, do the following:

```
Router::connect('/admin',array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true));
```

for example!

This will redirect you to: yoursite.com/admin

This way, you can follow your structure normally with your controllers inside the admin folder.

In the example I gave, it would look like this: admin/users/login.php

Comment: This approach means that every action would have to be mapped, what I need to be able to do is have all controller actions work without explicitly writing them in the routes. II believe it is not possible in Cake v2.